# ftpClient.listFiles("path") with mainframe

Tags: java, ftp, mainframe

I was trying to retrieve files from a mainframe FTP server,
so i was using this org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient method:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = ......
ftpClient.listFiles("path")
```

let's say the dir was "AAAA.BBBB.CCCC.DDDD":

```
ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("..");
FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles("AAAA.BBBB.CCCC.DDDD");
```

When I print out

```
files.length
```

result is 1. Doesn't matter if it's a file or a folder, the result is still 1. I want to know why.

My test on a regular, non-mainframe, ftp using a folder name and file names worked fine.

I wish to know:

> How to correctly traversal a directory in mainframe ftp.

Comment: Which FTP library are you using?

Comment: If the operating system is ZOS, it does not actually have directories. It does have PDS's which are bit like fairly limited zip files. For the most part PDS's can be treated like directories in FTP but there will be differences

Comment: so is listFiles working with mainframe file system PDS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two file systems available with [z/OS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0).  One is the "classic" file system (my term, I don't know how IBM differentiates) which has roots going back half a century to [OS/360](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS/360), the other is more recent and is [Unix](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=zos-unix-system-services) compatible.

You are using the "classic" file system.  There are no directories.  Sometimes there is syntactic sugar available in an FTP client that makes the dataset name qualifiers (the "AAAA" and "BBBB" parts between the dots) *seem like* directories.  They aren't.

I suggest you use wildcards in the argument to your `listFiles` method.  See if "AAAA.BBBB.CCCC.DDDD.**" gets you what you expect.

Something else you could try would be to pass the argument "AAAA.BBBB.CCCC" to your `changeWorkingDirectory` method.

Depending on the implementation of the library you're using, either of the above may do the equivalent of the ISPF [DSLIST](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=commands-dslist) command.

Comment: thanks for the reply, why u use ** for the wild card, not single *? i will try it out. thanks

Comment: @RuoboWang the ** matches 0 or more additional qualifiers, a * matches 1 or more additional qualifiers.  ISPF DSLIST pattern matching is different from regular expressions and also different from other OSs wildcard matching.

Answer (score 1):

I was investigating this issue with a customer's mainframe very recently, and the working solution was first adding a DefaultFtpSessionFactory with the following configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
   <property name="host" value="???.???.???.???" />
   <property name="port" value="21" />
   <property name="username" value="ftp" />
   <property name="password" value="ftp" />
   <property name="config">
      <bean class="org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClientConfig">
         <constructor-arg value="MVS" />
      </bean>
   </property>
</bean>
```

the filePattern we use on the session object is 'FILE.FILE.FILE.FILE.FILE.**'  (inlcuding the single quotes)

the java code for getting the list of file is

```
Session<FTPFile> session = factory.getSession();
FTPFile[] files = session.list("'FILE.FILE.FILE.FILE.FILE.**'");
```

Comment: Hi Bill, i was investigating this issue with a customer's mainframe very recently, and the working solution was first adding a DefaultFtpSessionFactory with the following configuration:

Comment: OK, good edit. Thanks. We can clear up now by removing the comments. I've started, and I'll get rid of this one when I see yours has gone.